# Architecture For Android Devices And Desktop Server Application

Tags: android, design-patterns, architecture, client-server

I'm designing an application where one or more devices can control an other one device. In the middle there is a Desktop Server.

In few word:

- One of the "Controller Devices" through an Activity take a command from the user and communicate it to the Server;
- The "Controlled Device" has a Service that listen for commands from Server;
- When the Controlled Device answers the Server has to inform all the "Controller Devices".

Which is the best Pattern, or Architecture, that can i use?

Comment: It looks like 'publish-subscribe', which - yes - implemented with the 'observer' pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mainly Observer pattern,but you don't need to build the architecture, google has already built it for you, using Google Cloud Messsaging (GCM).

Your client register/unregister to gcm and then sends data to your backend/server which in turn manipultes and sends data to gcm which in turn sends push notification to registered devices, then you device must has a receiver to send the data back to your application.

Here have a look [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

And here is a sample diagram that represents the gsm architecture, note that you can use any server instead of app engine

[image]

Comment: Very helpfull! I read about the feature to send a Messagge with a Payload ( 4 kb ). In my application there is the possibility that one Messagge contains a photo. Now is it better to implement my custom Observer Pattern or can i adapt this GCM?

Comment: On the other hand you can send image url from GCM and download it from device client, and if image was generated by a clien then it can be uploaded to server and server sends its url to GCM wihch then pushed to devices

Comment: Yes i think that i'm going to follow this way!